# tf.estimator.DNNClassifier not available

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to work with tensorflow, but the DNNClassifier (and the other estimators) are not available from tf.estimator.

I am running Python 3.6 within Anaconda on Windows 10. I used conda install tensorflow to load and import tensorflow as tf to import the package.

When I try to use DNNClassifier, I get the error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.estimator.estimator_lib' has no attribute 'DNNClassifier'
```

Have any others had this problem?

Comment: I think that this is an issue with the Anaconda, community supported, version of tensorflow. I reinstalled with pip and all of the functions are now available.

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Install using pip.  Install the CPU version unless you have an nvidia GPU.